# How can I improve this Point class

Tags: java, immutability

I'm writing a program that will need to use a limited set of Points to process an image.  I figure that I would implement it as an immutable/singleton style class.  Before going on to build more of the complex logic surrounding the class I wanted to get an opinion about the core class.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Point {
    private final int x,y;
    private final int hashCode;

    private static final HashMap<int[],Point> points = new HashMap<>();

    private Point(int x,int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.hashCode = new HashCodeBuilder().append(x).append(y).toHashCode();
    }
    public static Point getPoint(int x,int y){
        int [] candidate = new int[]{x,y};
        if(points.containsKey((candidate))){
            return points.get(candidate);
        }

        Point newPoint = new Point(x,y);
        points.put(candidate, newPoint);
        return newPoint;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object p){
        return this == p;
    }
}
```

I'm going to be using the class to do at least the following functions:

- Map different channels in an image by this `Point` class
- Define some static cached custom NavigableSets for ease of traversal
- Various Helper functions. In example, get all Points surrounding a `Point`

Given the information provided, what are some downsides of the provided implementation?

Note:  Putting the bulleted list before the code block breaks the display of the code block.  Bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your caching "singletony" stuff may be pointless.

It doesn't save on object creation, as you will always create a `candidate[]` each time you ask for a Point.  And, unless the Point gets reused, you use the memory for candidate **and** the `Map.Entry` in your HashMap.  So, very roughly speaking, unless each Point gets reused **three** times, your caching uses more memory.  And it always uses a more time.

If you don't cache, change your `equals` of course.

p.s. the rest seems fine, and immutable is good.  You could consider making x and y `public final` to be more compatible with other Point implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Everyone said very similar things, but I appreciate you pointed out the flaw in my implementation rather than just suggesting an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are worried about the occupied memory, there is another way to deal with it.

   I assuming you have limited dimension for your points, I would suggest to combine your x & y in one variable of long (in case your dimensions is 32 ints long), or even int (if you can fit one dimensions in 16 bit), this way you'll get boost in performance & memory.

   Other option is to use int[] array of your coordinates for a point, although that would take more space (since you would have to keep additional pointer reference).
2. Factory method in your implementation, will work only on single threaded applications, if you have multiple threads creating points, you would need to have some concurrency control in place. This would eat up your resources, because you would effectively need to lock on each point creation.
3. Another reason, why this Factory method is a bad idea, is that int[] arrays do not override equals and hashCode, *you can try to create 2 arrays with same content, to check*. So your HashMap would not simply work, and instead of saving memory you would not only create a new Point each time, but also add an entry to your HashMap and perform unnecessary calculations.

So either use Java primitives, or just create a new immutable Point each time if you need too, and go with it, don't overcomplicate with factoryMethods.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to create a Point class that would functionally work like a primitive.  3 had completely left my brain, but I *should* have known that.  1 *is* a good idea.  Do you happen to have an example of that off hand?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea of making the Point class immutable but then you went and complicated things with the instance cache.  It is not thread safe and it will leak memory because once a Point is created it will forever stay in the hashmap and will never be garbage collected.

Why not keep it simple and make a regular boring value class?  Your IDE will even generate it for you.

Then, if you really really **really** want to have an instance cache, use Guava's [Interner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) class instead of rolling your own.  The result will look something like this:

```
public class Point {
    final int x;
    final int y;

    private Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
    }

    static Interner<Point> instanceCache = Interners.newWeakInterner();

    public static Point of(int x, int y) {
        return instanceCache.intern(new Point(x,y));
    }

    public int getX() { return x; }

    public int getY() { return y; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Point other = (Point) o;
        return this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return x * 31 + y; }
}
```

Comment: Does the guava `Interners` not work with the equals method I implemented?